# Increase the x-values when plotting in python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to obtain a plot similar to this [one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yGHh6.png). Currently I have obtained the following [plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LMC6I.png). I think I can achieve the first plot by increasing the resolution of the x-axis ranging `[0 1]` for the blue line. Here is the code to generate these plots.

```
x_plot_new = np.arange(0,1,0.0001)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,5))
plt.scatter(x_train, t_train, c='black', label='Training Data')    
plt.plot(x_train, pred_train, label='Regression result M = 9')
plt.plot(x_n, function, c = 'red', label='f(x)')
plt.xticks(fontsize=14)
plt.yticks(fontsize=14)
plt.grid(True)
plt.legend(fontsize=16)
print(x_test)
print(x_train)
```

All of the variables have shape `(10,)` except `x_plot_new` which has shape `(10000,)` and so I want to plot `pred_train` using `x_plot_new`.

Addendum on finding `pred_train`:

```
def basis_functions(X, L):
    w = np.empty(L+1)
    for x in X:
        p = [x ** (order) for order in range(L+1)]
        w = np.vstack((w, p))
    return w[1:]

phi_train = basis_functions(x_train, 9) #polynomial
w_p = np.linalg.pinv(phi_train)
w = w_p@t_train

pred_train = phi_train @ w
```

`x_train`, `phi_train` all have shape `(10,)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how you generate your pred_train variable but assuming you have a function that takes in x values and gives y values called something like reg_func you should be able to get results similar to the picture using

```
plt.plot(x_plot_new, reg_func(x_plot_new), label='Regression result M = 9')
```

Updated answer with code I used for plot

```
x = np.linspace(0,10,10) 
y = np.sin(x) + 0.1 * rng.randn(10)  
phi_train = basis_functions(x, 9) #polynomial 
w_p = np.linalg.pinv(phi_train) 
w = w_p@y  
pred_train = phi_train @ w  
x_plot_new = np.arange(0,10,0.001)  
over_fit = basis_functions(x_plot_new, 9) 
over_fit_to_plot = over_fit @ w  
plt.scatter(x, y) 
plt.plot(x_plot_new, over_fit_to_plot)
```

Comment: I included an addendum to show how I am finding `pred_train` I was not using a function. The confusing part for me is that I cannot increase my x-values before that point of finding `pred_train` I need to increase them only for plotting purposes.

Comment: Hmm I haven't seen the basis_functions before, but I guess they create a matrix of the x values which you then perform a regression on?

I think you could try the following 
    pred_overfit = basis_functions(x_plot_new, 9)
    pred_overfit = pred_overfit @ w
and then plot it using 
    plt.plot(x_plot_new, pred_overfit, label='Regression result M = 9')

Comment: `basis_functions` is a polynomial basis function that I created I provide the x-values and the order of regression I require. Essentially its e^(order). I included it as well in the addendum

Comment: Your suggestion unfortunately did not work either. I think the code is correct though because for other model orders I am obtaining the correct plot. Only when it comes to model order = 9.

Comment: updated the answer with code that gave me plot similar to the one you had in original question.

Comment: Hi, your solution was correct I simply had a mistake in some other part of the code. Thanks

Comment: Hello @Love sorry to bother you but if you ever have the time I was working on a regularised least square regression model using Gaussian basis functions this time, with 100 datasets. I tried to plot one dataset which is suppose to be a distorted sine wave however I have not managed. I am attaching code in this link -> https://pastebin.com/jnN8RkPL  . I thought you could help me since you were very helpful when it came to regression models, again only if you have the time.

Comment: I looked at it but I have a hard time understanding what you are trying to do, could you explain how you are trying to format you x-data and y-data? because now you split them and then concatenate them directly after, it makes me somewhat confused.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. To answer your question I was actually splitting my data incorrectly, instead I created a function to partition my data in sets of 25. Anyways I managed but thank you nonetheless for your time.